# jQuery: invoke function once on event-handler declaration

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery('select').on('change EVENT_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR', function() {
    var select_box = jQuery(this);
    var id = select_box.data('id');
    var details = jQuery('#details_' + id);
    if(select_box.val()) {
        details.show();
    } else {
        details.hide();
    }
});
-------------------------------------------
jQuery('select').triggerHandler('change');
// or name the anonymous function and invoke it immediately
```

Is there an event like "load" (doesn't work) or so that would run the function once right after the declaration to save the code beneath the line? Or is there another way to invoke the anon function immediately?

It's nothing life changing but I always wonder when I write code like this.

Comment: I don't understand the "right after the declaration to save the code beneath the line" part.

Comment: I meant if I can spare this code:

jQuery('select').triggerHandler('change');
// or name the anonymous function and invoke it immediately

by using an additional event that's executed immediatelly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can chain:

```
jQuery('select').on('change', function(e){ ... }).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Exactly what I do with select elements that affect the page on change.

Comment: OK, suspected that's not possible

Answer (score 0):

The method you have now of triggering the event immediately after create the handler is a fine pattern to use. An alternative is to declare a function for the handler and call it straight away. Something like this:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var select_box = jQuery(this);
    var id = select_box.data('id');
    var details = jQuery('#details_' + id);
    if (select_box.val()) {
        details.show();
    } 
    else {
        details.hide();
    }
}

jQuery('select').on('change EVENT_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR', myFunction);
$.proxy(myFunction, $('select'))();
```

Note I have used `$.proxy` here as your function relies on the scope of the `select` causing the event.

Comment: This approach would be what I had in mind regarding the comment "// or name the anonymous function and invoke it immediately"